# Build fails on older Git branch after checking out another with build.gradle specifying newest version of Sass jar

Tags: ruby, gradle, build-process, compass-sass, build.gradle

I upgraded my local Compass and Sass to their latest versions and fixed some errors caused by deprecated code per the latest Sass (3.4.9). I checked those into a branch and the changes include updating a build.gradle file in which it specifies a Sass jar also of the latest version (This was created and uploaded to nexus by another co-worker). For testing, I had another co-worker, who is using an older version of Sass, check out my branch. It built fine. But when he switched back to another branch, it failed, showing the same errors I got after I updated Sass. We verified he is still using Sass 3.2.1. I had him remove a cached file (sass-3.4.9.gem) and directory (sass-3.4.9). The build still failed. I'm not at all familiar with build.gradle files and such. I'm hoping anyone has insight on what happened and how to fix this.

EDIT: Below are two error examples. All the other errors I get refer to not being able to extend a class -

> Building > :compileSassWARNING: The compass/css3/box module is DEPRECATED and will be removed in the next release. Please use compass/css3/flexbox instead.
>            on line 4 of /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-core-1.0.1/stylesheets/compass/css3/_box.scss
>            from line 11 of /Users/sueannaj/dev/workspace/zephyr_css/scss/sass/shared/includes/_imports.scss
>            from line 14 of /Users/sueannaj/dev/workspace/zephyr_css/scss/sass/twitter-main.scss

```
error scss/sass/t-store-main.scss (Line 6 of scss/sass/touch/modules/sub/_default-buttons.scss: ".button-group" failed to @extend ".tabbed-layout".
```

The selector ".tabbed-layout" was not found.
Use "@extend .tabbed-layout !optional" if the extend should be able to fail.

For reference, I'm on Mac 10.8.5 and ruby 1.8.7. Someone here figured a fix, and I will answer my own question.

Comment: Please edit your post: copy/paste the exact commands you're using, and the exact error messages. Also it may help if you post the ruby version you're using ("ruby -v") and the OS version (e.g. Ubuntu 14.04). And if your error message contains information about "SSL" or "Certificates" then read http://railsapps.github.io/openssl-certificate-verify-failed.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two cached files and one directory that needed removing -

~/.gradle/caches

.gradle

build

The last two, .gradle and build, live in the project directory. .gradle/caches is in the user's home directory.